# Showing days left from a date entry?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So if I have `<ons-input style="padding-bottom: 15px;" type="date" id="expiration" required="required"></ons-input>`, would it be possible to take the date entered and display the days left until that date is reached and count down each day? exp: if todays 2020-12-4 and I input a new date 2020-12-6, then you have 2 days left, then tomorrow it would display 1 day left.

HTML:

```
    <template id="mylist.html">
    <ons-page id='mylist'>
      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left">
          <ons-toolbar-button onclick="fn.open()">
            <ons-icon icon="md-menu"></ons-icon>
          </ons-toolbar-button>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
          My List
        </div>
        
      </ons-toolbar>
      <div style="padding-top: 15px; text-align: center;">

        <ons-input type="text" class="select-input--underbar" id="food" placeholder="Enter item here . . ."></ons-input>
        <br></br>
        <label for="expiration">Expiration Date:</label>
        <ons-input style="padding-bottom: 15px;" type="text" id="expiration" placeholder = "YYYY-MM-DD" value = ""></ons-input>
        
        <ons-button class="btnAdd" id="start-count" modifier="large" onclick="addItem()">Add Item</ons-button>
        
      </div>   

      <ons-list id='foodList'>
        <ons-list-header>Listed Items:</ons-list-header>
        <div class="countdown-content">
        <ons-list-item>
          <span id="day"></span> Days
          <span id="hour"></span> Hours
          <span id="minute"></span> Minutes
          <span id="second"></span> Seconds
        </ons-list-item>
        </div>
      </ons-list>    
    </ons-page>
  </template>
```

JavaScript:

```
    function listItems(tx, rs)
{
  var output = '';
  var foodList = document.getElementById('foodList');

  for(i = 0; i < rs.rows.length; i++)
  {
    var row = rs.rows.item(i);
    output += "<ons-list-item>" + "Item: " + row.food + " " + "<br></br>" + "Expiration: " + row.expiration + "<br></br>" + "Days: " + day + "<br></br>" + "Hours: " + hour + "<br></br>" + "Minutes: " + minute + "<br></br>" + "Seconds: " + second +
    "<div class=\"right\"> <ons-button onclick='deleteItems(" + row.ID + ");') ><ons-icon icon=\"trash\"></ons-icon></ons-button></div>" +
    "</ons-list-item>";
  }

  foodList.innerHTML = output;

}

function addItem() 
{
  var foodText = document.getElementById("food");
  var expText = document.getElementById("expiration");
  var foodVal = foodText.value;
  var expVal = expText.value;

  db.transaction(function(tx)
  {
    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO foodLogs (food, expiration) VALUES (?, ?)", [foodVal, expVal])
  });

  foodText.value = "";
  expText.value = "";
  fn.load("mylist.html");
}

function deleteItems(id)
{
  db.transaction(function(tx) 
  {
    tx.executeSql("DELETE FROM foodLogs WHERE ID=?", [id], gotSuccess, gotError);
  });
}

var timer = null;
var end;
var toZero;
var btn = document.getElementById("btnAdd");
var oDay = document.getElementById("day");
var oHour = document.getElementById("hour");
var oMinute = document.getElementById("minute");
var oSecond = document.getElementById("second");
var endtime = document.getElementById("expiration");
var startBtn = document.getElementById("start-count");
toZero = oDay.innerHTML = oHour.innerHTML = oMinute.innerHTML = oSecond.innerHTML = "00";
startBtn.onclick = function() {
  end = endtime.value;
  if (!end) {
    alert("Please enter date！")
    return false;
  };
  countDown(tx, rs);
  timer = setInterval(countDown, 1000);
}

function countDown(tx, rs) {
  var timedate = new Date(Date.parse(end.replace(/-/g, "/"))); 
  var now = new Date(); 
  var date = (timedate.getTime() - now.getTime()) / 1000; 
  var day = Math.floor(date / (60 * 60 * 24));
  var _hour = date - day * 60 * 60 * 24;
  var hour = Math.floor(_hour / (60 * 60));
  var _minute = _hour - hour * 60 * 60;
  var minute = Math.floor(_minute / (60));
  var _second = _minute - minute * 60;
  var second = Math.floor(_second);
}

  function toDou(n) {
      if (n < 10) {
        return '0' + n;
      } else {
        return '' + n;
      }
    } 
  if (date > 0) {
    oDay.innerHTML = toDou(day);
    oHour.innerHTML = toDou(hour);
    oMinute.innerHTML = toDou(minute);
    oSecond.innerHTML = toDou(second);
  } else {
    btn.className = "";
    btn.className = "btn";
    btn.onclick = function() {
      alert("oops")
    }
    endtime.value = "";
    clearInterval(timer);
    toZero;
  }
```

**Edit:** Current error is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null" at line 106 which is `toZero = oDay.innerHTML = oHour.innerHTML = oMinute.innerHTML = oSecond.innerHTML = "00";`, haven't gotten any time output yet. It is instead giving undefined.

**Edit:** For the days, hours, minutes, and seconds I am receiving [object HTMLSpanElement] instead of the actual values behind the elements when viewing the page? Overall, the value isn't being read correctly.

Code Example: https://codepen.io/Wssoop/pen/poEbzve

Comment: WebSQL is an **abandoned** and obsolete web technology that was replaced with IndexedDB. It was abandoned back in 2010, see the big warning on it's own spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/ - why are you using it?

Comment: I had started working on this a while ago, I didn't realize at the time that it was abandoned. I plan to eventually switch it over, but I simply haven't had time to, so I've stuck with it for now.

Comment: It looks like `startBtn.onclick = function() {` is missing a closing `}`, right before `function countDown() {`.

Comment: Ah, true. I see that and changed it, I'm still troubleshooting things for now.